# C# Launch Child WPF in a new Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am looking for help in the following issue that I am experiencing.

I've spent two days now searching thru this site and thru Google - trying many different things to get my issue resolved and so far I have had no luck.  I know that I have not yet done sufficient reading on multi threading which will be my next To Do item in my learning journey.  I am fairly new to C# so please be gentle.

My main WPF application has a button which I've labeled "INFO".  On the CLICK event of the "INFO" button I need to launch a seperate WPF which simply contains the WEBBROWSER object.  I am displaying our intranet site in the webbrowser object.

I need to be able to accomplish the following:

1. I need to launch the WPFBrowser in its own THREAD in order for the WPF to be fully available even if a dialog box is launched.
2. I then need to be able to also make sure that the WPF which is in its own thread to be re-activated when the user clicks on the INFO button if the thread is already running.
3. Also when the Main WPF is closed I need make sure that any open threads are closed as well.

I am looking for the most simple solution possible.

Sample code of what I have in place

// this is declare right above  public MainWindow()
    Thread newWindowThread;

```
private async void btn_LaunchWPFBrowser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
            try
            {
                    if (newWindowThread == null)
                    {
                        newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            var wpfwindow = new WPF_Windows.wpf_Browser();
                            wpfwindow.Show();

                            wpfwindow.Closed += (sender2, e2) => wpfwindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

                            // Start the Dispatcher Processing
                            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                        });

                        // Set the apartment state
                        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  //setting new thread’s apartment state to STA, this is a WPF requirement
                        newWindowThread.Start();
                    }
                    else if (newWindowThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
                    {
                        //wpfwindow.Activate();

                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string additionalMessage = "In method '" + TraceCallerClass.TraceCaller() + "' ";

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

            }
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be running two UI threads, instead you should spawn another singleton application that you kill when your main application starts, I think that would solve a lot of your problems.

Comment: thanks for your response Ron - I am looking for the most straight forward easiest way to get this to work.. I will like to keep the WPF browser launched within the same exe that the user has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
private object syncGate = new object();
private Thread browserWindowThread;
private Window browserWindow;

private void btn_LaunchWPFBrowser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lock (syncGate)
        {
            if (browserWindowThread == null)
            {
                browserWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    var wpfwindow = new WPF_Windows.wpf_Browser();
                    wpfwindow.Show();
                    wpfwindow.Closed += (sender2, e2) => wpfwindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                    lock (syncGate)
                        browserWindow = wpfwindow;
                    // Start the Dispatcher Processing
                    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                    lock (syncGate)
                    {
                        browserWindow = null;
                        browserWindowThread = null;
                    }
                });
                browserWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
                // Set the apartment state
                browserWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  //setting new thread’s apartment state to STA, this is a WPF requirement
                browserWindowThread.Start();
            }
            else if (browserWindow != null)
            {
                browserWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool>(browserWindow.Activate));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string additionalMessage = "In method '" + TraceCallerClass.TraceCaller() + "' ";

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
    lock (syncGate)
    {
        if (browserWindow != null)
            browserWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(browserWindow.Close));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ivan Stoeve - thank you for your solution.  Your solution is meeting my three requirements including simple coding. 

However, I am not sure why - when I am stepping thru and I put my cursor over  browserWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool>(browserWindow.Activate));  the application crashes.  Getting "An unhandled win32 exception occured".  I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I noticed that I first get the message that says "Getting Data tip text" then the app crashes. then the "An unhandled win32 exception occured" error comes up.  I am using Visual Studio 2015"

Comment: Me too. Well, all I can say VS2015 has many bugs - waiting for Update 1, 2, 3... :-)

Comment: So it sounds like it is a BUG... in that case...thank you for the solution and I will mark this as the answer.  I will test a further with the compiled exe which I assume should not crash.

Comment: Before you start debugging, go to `Debug->Options->General` and check `Use Managed Compatibility Mode`

Comment: I just tried it and now the app does not crash when stepping thru in the debugger....thanks

Answer (score 0):

use Task instead of Thread for easy close process   .
My offer use this way ...

```
public interface IWinOwnerCollection
    {
        List<Window> WinOwnerCollection { get; }
    }

class MainWindow : Window, IWinOwnerCollection
    {
        public List<Window> WinOwnerCollection { get; private set; }

        Task newWindowTask;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WinOwnerCollection = new List<Window>();
            this.Closed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                newWindowTask = null;
            };
        }

        private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (newWindowTask == null)
                {
                    newWindowTask = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            var wpfwindow = new Window1();
                            wpfwindow.WinOwner = this;
                            wpfwindow.Show();

                            wpfwindow.WinOwner.Closed += (o, args) =>
                            {
                                wpfwindow.Close();
                                //newWindowTask.Abort();
                            };
                        }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
                    });
                    newWindowTask.Start();
                }
                else if (newWindowTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    foreach (var window in WinOwnerCollection)
                    {
                        window.Activate();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }


    }
```

Browser Window add this property :=>

```
public MainWindow WinOwner
        {
            get { return _winOwner; }
            set
            {
                _winOwner = value;
                if (value is IWinOwnerCollection)
                {
                    ((IWinOwnerCollection)value).WinOwnerCollection.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you MK7 for your solution and response.  THis is what I love the most from stackoverflow...the great people that are willing to help :)